# The neighbourhood of a root of a continuous function

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing

I have been tearing my hair out with what I thought (and probably is!) a very simple question:

Let $f$ be continuous real (non-zero) function on $\mathbb{R}$ with $f(a)=0$ for some $a\in\mathbb{R}$. Does there exist $\delta>0$ such that $f(x)\neq 0$ for $(a,a+\delta)$?

My intuition (which is all I am currently working with) tells me that this should be true: if it is zero at $x=a$ then surely it must be either (strictly) positive or negative in some region around $x=a$. I was hoping to form a proof of this (maybe using $\epsilon$'s and $\delta$'s) but currently to no avail. 
I have tried invoking the definition of continuity and the intermediate value theorem, but all my efforts seem to just *put* in the answer rather than *prove* it is true. I even thought that it might be a proposition or theorem already in my notes or book, but haven't found it in the literature I have scoured. Help or pointers would be much appreciated!

Comment: Your function could have a "plateau" , for example it could be $0$ for $0\le x\le 1$. In this case,your claim is false, if you choose , for example, $a=0.5$

Comment: I suspect you have the idea of *analytic function* in mind, for which this is true.

Comment: Try the piecewise function$f$ such that $f(0) = 0$ and $f(x) = x\,{\sin}(1/x)$ when $x \ne 0$. Then $f$ is everywhere continuous (even at $x=0$), but every neighborhood of $x=0$ contains infinitely many zeros of $f$.

Comment: Excellent counterexamples @quasi (and Peter) - thanks! What I had in mind was $f$ being a rational polynomial - which covers it being analytic right? How could this be proved?

Comment: @AloneAndConfused: I don't deserve too much credit -- it's a standard counterexample for a _lot_ of things (so file it away for future use).

Comment: Thanks @Peter. I recall some notes on isolated zeros so back to the books!

Comment: @AloneAndConfused My formulation was not quite exact. "Isolated zeros" is a better word. Therefore I deleted my comment, but it seems it was helpful nevertheless.

Comment: It's funny what can trigger one's mind! The word "separated" in your comment set me on the path!

Comment: And that's the main thing :)

Comment: @AloneAndConfused: does this fact ring any bells: if $f$ is a non-constant polynomial of degree $n$, then $f$ has at most $n$ roots? So, for any $a$ and $\delta > 0$,  if $f(x) = 0$ for all $x \in (a, a +\delta)$ then $f$ has more than $n$ roots and hence must be constant.

Comment: Very nice simple argument  @RobArthan - thanks!